# SVN: undo a merge with local changes

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I was on version 100, with local changes.

I did an svn up to reach HEAD (which is revision 200). Then I was ill adviced to revert back to revision 150, with my local changes, in command: `svn merge -r HEAD:150 .`

Now I actually want to go back to revision 200 with my local changes. svn up doesn't do anything, because I appear to still have file missings. I know because a file A.cpp was in revision 200 but not in my local working copy.

If I do svn status, I see a bizzare "D" in front of A.cpp. they seem to think I want to delete this file I don't even own.

What state am I in now, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In brief, your current checked out repo is messed up - it has a combination of your changes as well as a set of uncommitted changes to go back from HEAD -> r150. If you committed at this point, it would have the effect of removing all the changes that happened from 150:HEAD, and then adding in your changes.

If trying to do a re-merge: `svn merge -r 150:HEAD .` doesn't work (and generally it won't), then I would suggest the following:

- assuming you have your current workspace `<currws>`
- checkout a *second* copy of the workspace, at revision 150: `svn co -r 150 <svn url> <newws>`. This will give you a directory `<newws>`
- `(cd <currws>; tar cf - --exclude .svn .) | (cd <newws>; tar xf -)`. This will take all the files & directories from `<currws>` and copy them into `<newws>`.

Take inventory of the new directory - it should now contain copies of only your changes - some of these may need to be SVN added to the workspace; or if you have deletes, they will need to be re-deleted on the `<newws>`. You can pre-remove all the files/folders from new-ws prior to the tar, and anything that appears after the tar with a `!` indicates a file that you removed with your changes, anything with a `?` is a file that needs adding, and the remainder should be `M` entries.

Bring the new workspace up to HEAD - `svn up <newws>` should work in this case.

verify that everything's working and that it only contains your changes.

make a patch file, get it code reviewed and then commit it.

I'm pretty sure this will get you back on-track; although I don't have a tree to check against with the spotty network connectivity I have.